# Python Rest API test case

Tags: python, rest, python-requests, pytest, wadl

I need to develop test case for testing the rest services and the only resource provided to me by my client is WADL file and with the help of this I need to come up with the rest client test case. Have written using requests & pytest modules of python. however not sure if it covers all the scenarios for this WADl..help much appreciated to find out gaps in the test case if any

WADL:-

```
resources base="http://mygame.herokuapp.com/rest/">
 <resource path="nextgame">
   <method id="getNextGame" name="GET">
    <response>
     <representation mediaType="text/plain"/>
    </response>
    </method>
</resource>
<resource path="lastGame">
    <method id="getLastGame" name="GET">
     <response>
       <representation mediaType="text/plain"/>
     </response>
    </method>
</resource>
<resource path="recentGame">
    <method id="getRecentGame" name="GET">
     <response>
      <representation mediaType="text/plain"/>
     </response>
    </method>
</resource>
</resources>
</application>
```

My Python Test case:

```
import pytest
import requests
@pytest.mark.parametrize("input,expected", [
    ("http://mygame.herokuapp.com/rest/lastgame", 'XYZ'),
    ("http://mygame.herokuapp.com/rest/nextgame", 'ABC'),
    ("http://mygame.herokuapp.com/rest/recentmovie", 'DEF')
])
def test_eval(input, expected):
    r = requests.get(input)
    assert r.text == expected
    assert r.status_code==200
    assert r.headers['Content-Type']=='text/plain'
```